# Poor performance using Proprietary AMD drivers in wine, is there a way to improve it?

Tags: drivers, wine, games, radeon

Well lets start:

- I have the proprietary drivers installed,
- I am using Ubuntu 13.04,
- my Video board is an AMD Radeon HD 7970M with 2gb of Vram,
- in a Clevo/Sager p150hm,
- 6gb ram ddr3,
- Intel core i7 processor 2.4ghz

Wine:

- Stronghold Crusader HD: FINE,
- Diablo 2 HD mod: Fine,
- MOHAA: slow at max setting,
- Ether Saga: slow
- Heroes of the three kingdoms: Slow,
- MK KE don't even start,

  - d3d error attributed to lack vram,
- The kings Of Figther XIII: Slow as continental drift,
- Soul Reaver1: Good (is a really old game),
- Blood omen1: Good (even older)

All the games that run slow in Ubuntu I play on ultra settings in Windows 7 x64, and in some cases two games at time.

Comment: this is the output"
direct rendering: Yes
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon HD 7970M
    GL_KTX_buffer_region, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_conditional_render,"  the word render is in RED :S

Comment: also this comand will help me??? and how it go? "__GL_THREADED_OPTIMIZATIONS=1 WINEDEBUG=-all wine wow-64 -opengl"

Comment: ok is organized now :P

Comment: anyone????please, help me with this, i have a lot of originals games that i will like to play but is so slow on wine........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, firts of all, *Wine is a gamble*. It won't magically allows you run any Windows software without problems. That said, you should check the [WineHQ page](http://appdb.winehq.org) for each game to know the status:

- [**Medal of Honor: Allied Assault**](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=662): Version 1.1 runs apparently fine with a minor tweak while 1.11 do not. For 1.1 running fine you should use either, a script or run the commands yourself `MESA_EXTENSION_MAX_YEAR=2002 wine MOHAA.exe`. Here is the script:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  cd ~/MyWinePrefixes/.MoH/path/to/your/game.exe
  #Run with GL extensions disabled/nVidia card
  WINEPREFIX=~/MyWinePrefixes/.MoH __GL_ExtensionStringVersion=17700 wine ./MOHAA.EXE
  ```

  (The scripts needs to be tweaked to fit your exact system)

  You will need wine version 1.5.7 for the fixes to work. Read the comments [here](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=662).
- **[Ether Saga Online](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=9278)**: This is the Online version, I don't know if it deffers from yours but is the only one in the WineHQ. Version 504 seems [to work flawlesssy](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26211) in Wine 1.2.3 (but Arch Linux), while 510 had problems with the WASD keys, but apparently works [without glitches in windowed mode](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=26220).
- **[Heroes Of Three Kingdoms](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=20840)**: This application was not tested since June of 2010. Feel free to suscribe to WineHQ and submit your tests. Remember that perfomance is not important for the tests, but that the applications installs and **run**.
- **[Mortal Kombat Komplete Edition](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=28482)**: Here you were unlucky. The latest test in Aug 15, 2013, reports the game works fine and fast even with High video Detail out the box for wine 1.7.0. But seems that it is a know problem and has it fix, thanks to Mike Vaughn:

  > If the video settings are left unchanged after being auto-configured, the game will fail to start until its setting files (drive_c/users/[user]/Application Data/MKKE) are deleted. What's weird is the automatic configuration set everything to minimum settings; I had to adjust them to medium/high before I was able to start the game again without resetting its configuration. This isn't a huge deal for me since my somewhat modest system can still handle it without noticeable frame loss, but it might be an issue for others.

  You heard the man.
- **[King Of Fighters XIII](http://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=13816)**: Only old (Jan 02 2012) test results that placed the game with Platinium (the highest rank). Feel free to update the tests.

As you should have understood by now, Wine needs some tweaks for some games run flawlessy or they won't run at all. The tests are meant for each part of the software while the perfomance is placed at last over functionality. The community behind WineHQ is proactive and they test everything they get hold for each version of wine so bugs introduced in one version will be fixed in the other. Read the wine [help page](http://appdb.winehq.org/help/), to know how you can help to get better perfomance with Windows applications (and games).